# Check which range a number is within

Tags: python, range

I need to find which range a number, in this case `value`, is within. I cannot find any other way to set `i` to what I need other than this:

```
if value < -64:
  i = 0
elif value < -32:
  i = 1
elif value < -16:
  i = 2
elif value < -8:
  i = 3
elif value < -4:
  i = 4
elif value < -2:
  i = 5
elif value < -1:
  i = 6
elif value < -0.5:
  i = 7
elif value < 0:
  i = 8
elif value < 0.5:
  i = 9
elif value < 1:
  i = 10
elif value < 2:
  i = 11
elif value < 4:
  i = 12
elif value < 8:
  i = 13
elif value < 16:
  i = 14
elif value < 32:
  i = 15
elif value < 64:
  i = 16
else:
  i = 17
```

This is terrible code and I hate it. Is there any way I can do something like this?

```
ranges = [-64, -32, -16 ... 32, 64]
i = find_which_range(value, ranges)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, check out [this tutorial on `for` loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp).

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the wider context of your program. This feels like an anti-pattern / code smell to begin with.

Comment: I need to create a one-hot label for tensorflow. The value is a percentage, and I need to find which index of an array of zeros to set to one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/bisect.html):

```
import bisect

ranges = [-64, -32, -16, -8, -4, -2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]

print(bisect.bisect(ranges, -65))
# 0

print(bisect.bisect(ranges, -64))
# 1

print(bisect.bisect(ranges, 63))
#16

print(bisect.bisect(ranges, 64))
# 17
```

`bisect.bisect(l, value)` returns the index at which `value` would have to be inserted in `l`, such that all values to the left are less than `value`. It will also be fast to search a large list, as it uses a bisection algorithm.

Comment: Exactly. This is not only _nicer_ than the original solution - it is also faster ;)

Answer (score 2):

Based off the way you described you could do something like this:

```
ranges = [-64, -32, -16, -8, -4, -2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]

def build_ranges(power):
    ranges = [-0.5, 0, 0.5]
    for i in range(power):
        ranges.append(2**i)
        ranges.append(-2**i)
    return sorted(ranges)

def find_which_range(value, ranges):
    for i, range in enumerate(sorted(ranges)):
        if value < range:
            return i
    return None

output = find_which_range(value, ranges)
```

Comment: You should include the default case for the scenario in which `value > 64`

Comment: Could expand this to have a helper function that generates `ranges` between any 2 powers of 2

Comment: The array look like `[... -2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2 ...]`, but other than that, thanks! This works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Mathew provided a looping solution that works fine. But also observe that you are checking basically, which powers of 2 your number is between. Thus, you can take the log.

```
import math
a_value = abs(value)
sign = 1 if value > 0 else -1
lg_value = math.log2(a_value)
range_ = (2**(sign*math.floor(lg_value)), 2**(sign*math.ceil(lg_value)))
```

note that slight modifications are required for ranges < 1.

Comment: That is much cleaner, but because I have no clue as to whats actually happening, I'm going to use the looping method. Thanks tho.

Comment: being easy to understand is important @NeilMacneale! No problems with that :). I did edit the answer though to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

To find the right range, you can iterate over each range using `zip` function, like this:

```
ranges = [-64, -32, -16, -8, -4, -2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]

i = 9

for p, n in zip(ranges[:-1], ranges[1:]):
    if p <= i < n:
        r = p, n
        break
else:
    raise ValueError(i)

print(r)
```

You get: (8, 16)

Then you can use a mapping between each range and target values, something like this:

```
mapping = {
  (-64, -32): 1,
  (-32, -16): 2,
  (-16, -8): 3
}

print(mapping[(-32, -16)])
2
```

Answer (score 1):

People already provided much shorter (and efficient) solutions. I am just posting here my attempt just to show one more way and logic to approach the problem using list comprehension.

```
def find_which_range(value, ranges):
    if value <= min(ranges):
        c = 0
    elif value >= max(ranges): 
        c = len(ranges)
    else:
        c = [i+1 for i in range(len(ranges)-1) if ranges[i] <= value <= ranges[i+1]][0]
    return c

value = -9
i = find_which_range(value, ranges)
```