# How to efficiently find which range a number falls into?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, range

I was asked the following question in a job interview:

> Given a graduated income tax system as follows:
>
> - Up to 10000 is taxed at 10%
> - 10001 to 50000 is taxed at 20%
> - 50001 and above is taxed at 30%
>
> Write a program to calculate the taxes on a given income.
>
> Example:
>
> - Taxes on 15000 would be (20% of 5000 + 10% of 10000) = 2000
> - Taxes on 60000 would be (30% of 10000 + 20% of 40000 + 10% of 10000) =
>     12000

I came up with the following pseudocode:

```
list = (
    (1, 10000, 0.1)
    (10001, 50000, 0.2)
    (50001, infinity, 0.3)
)

taxableIncome = income
taxes = 0
while taxableIncome > 0
    find e in list such that taxableIncome is in range [e[1], e[2]]
    taxes += taxableIncome - e[1] + 1
    taxableIncome = e[1] - 1

return taxes
```

The above works, but takes quadratic time in the worst case in the number of items in the list. Consider the case for income = 60000; the code loops 3 times, each time potentially scanning through the whole list.

Is there a faster way to find out which range the income falls into? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51641395/839733) question has some Python solutions, but I'm interested in a generic algorithmic solution, not a library.

Comment: You should start by precalculating the tax on the amount below the start of the bracket, because it's constant.

Comment: @MarkRansom I don’t understand what bracket you’re referring to. Once you find the appropriate bracket, the rest of the problem is almost trivial. Question is, how do you find the bracket efficiently?

Comment: Do they not have `if` statements in this pseudocode language of yours? With only 3 brackets, anything else would be overkill.

Comment: :) of course any high-level programming language supports `if`, but I was asked to make the code easily extensible. That made sense, since no one hires a developer based on their capability to write two `if` and one `else` statement.

Comment: It depends on if the goal was readability, extensibility, or efficiency. The `if` statement wins on both readability and efficiency for the case you were given. Only if you didn't know the number of brackets in advance would another approach be better.

Comment: why do you need that `find` inside the loop? Just iterate over the brackets, apply the tax rate, subtract from income while aggregating the tax. Should only take O(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here: @MBo's answer got me thinking (upvoted him for that), but unfortunately, he didn't explain it in a manner that was lucid enough for me, so here we go.

Let `N` be the number of brackets.

**NAIVE APPROACH:** Linear search for the appropriate tax bracket, compute tax on the excess income in the bracket, and then recursively compute the taxes on the taxable income below the bracket. For example, income `15000` falls in the bracket that starts at `10001`; the taxes for this bracket is `(15000 - 10000) * 0.2 = 1000` + taxes on `10000`.
This works, but linear search may take `O(N)` in the worst case, and if the initial income falls in the highest
bracket, the code would loop N times. We end up with a O(N^2) algorithm.

**BETTER APPROACH:** Binary search for the bracket, and then proceed as in the naive approach. `O(N log(N))`.

**DYNAMIC PROGRAMMING APPROACH:** This problem exhibits both of the two criteria for applying dynamic programming,
optimal substructure, and overlapping subproblems. Why? The total taxes for each bracket is the sum of the taxes for the current bracket, and the taxes for the remaining taxable income. For each bracket, the recursive solution computes the taxes for the lower brackets over and over again.

Thus, we precompute and memoize the taxes for the taxable income up to the previous bucket in a bottom-up fashion.
This takes `O(N)` time. Binary search for the bracket takes `log(N)` time. Computing the taxes now takes `O(1)` times, giving us a linear time algorithm overall.

**Scala code:** Feel free to adapt to your favorite programming language.

```
def taxes(income: Int, brackets: IndexedSeq[(Int, Double)]): Double = {
    val dp = brackets
      .zipWithIndex
      .foldLeft((0d, IndexedSeq.empty[(Int, Double, Double)])) { case ((sum, acc), (cur, i)) =>
        val taxesOnPrevBracket = if (i > 0) {
          val prev = brackets(i - 1)
          (cur._1 - prev._1) * prev._2
        } else 0d
        val cumulativeTaxes = sum + taxesOnPrevBracket

        (cumulativeTaxes, acc :+ (cur._1, cur._2, cumulativeTaxes))
      }
      ._2

    @tailrec
    def findBracket(start: Int, end: Int): Int = {
      if (end - start <= 1) start
      else {
        val mid = start + (end - start) / 2
        if (income > brackets(mid)._1) findBracket(mid, end)
        else findBracket(start, mid)
      }
    }

    val br = dp(findBracket(0, brackets.size - 1))
    val inc = income - br._1 + 1
    val tx = inc * br._2 + br._3
    println(s"Taxable income: $income, bracket: $br, taxes: $tx")
    tx
}
```

`brackets` here is a sequence of tuples, of the starting values (thanks @Dillon Davis for the idea) and the tax rate.

**Edit July 2021:**

The crucial takeaway is that the tax in the highest bracket is variable depending on the income, but taxes in the lower brackets are constant. For example, for income 15000 that falls in the second bracket, we don't know the excess amount to be taxed according to the second bracket ahead of time. Once we tax that, the remaining 10000 falls in the first bucket and the tax on that can be precomputed. Here's a Python solution.

```
import bisect

brackets = [
    (1, 0.1),
    (10001, 0.2),
    (50001, 0.3)
]
starts = [x for x, _ in brackets]
precomputed = []
cumulative_sum = 0
for i in range(len(brackets) - 1):
    cumulative_sum += (starts[i + 1] - starts[i]) * brackets[i][1]
    precomputed.append(cumulative_sum)

for income in [9000, 15000, 60000]:
    i = bisect.bisect_right(starts, income)
    i -= 1
    
    excess = income - brackets[i][0] + 1
    taxes = excess * brackets[i][1]
    if i > 0:
        taxes += precomputed[i - 1]

    print(f"Taxes on income {income} is: {taxes}")
```

Answer (score 5):

Precalculate tax value for the start of each range and include this value in list.

Also I removed excessive upper limit as Dillon Davis noticed in comments and changed lower value to the end of previous range to make formula more exact

```
 list = (
        (0, 0, 0.1)
        (10000, 1000, 0.2)
        (50000, 9000, 0.3)
    )
```

For given income find appropriate range with linear search (if number of ranges is small) or with binary search (if there is a lot of ranges - dozens, hundreds etc)

Then just calculate tax with simple formula

```
  tax  = e[2] + (income - e[1]) * e[3]
```

[image]

For income 15000 we can find

```
range = 2nd interval (10000, 1000, 0.2)
tax = 1000 + (15000 - 10000) * 0.2 = 
      1000 + 5000 * 0.2 = 2000
```

Or (using Dillon Davis suggestion)

```
  tax  = income * e[3] + (e[2] -  e[1]) * e[3])
  tax  = income * e[3] + e[2]'
```

with precalculated  `e2' = (e[2] -  e[1]) * e[3])` value for every range

Overall complexity is linear or logarithmic (with BS)

Comment: but to calculate the total tax you still need to go through all the brackets up to that point, so what is the point of using BS to locate it?

Comment: @Lucas Kot-Zaniewski  Total taxes for range start (0,1000,9000 in my example) are calculated only once when filling the list. Then for many `income` queries we can just use them.

Comment: You can exclude the upper limit on each bracket since its never used (and is just one less than the start of the next bracket anyways), and can also simplify your equation. `e[3] + (income - e[1]) * e[4] == income * e[4] + (e[3] - e[1] * e[4])` The last bit is constant, so you can just replace it with a different constant `e[3]` for `income * e[4] + e[3]`.

Comment: @MBo ah ok I see now that you have amended the input list. The old Space vs. Compute tradeoff. Your solution would be good for a large number of queries on a fixed number of tax systems which is probably what they were going for. Cool

Comment: @Lucas Kot-Zaniewski As far as I understand, list is stored in any case, so there is no new space requirements.

Comment: @MBo well if it's stored then you are introducing a new field to the table, either way it costs auxiliary space as it wasn't in OP's input structure

Comment: @Lucas Kot-Zaniewski Author suggested that structure for discussion. With last correction the list takes exactly the same space. In any case, introducing new simple field does not change space requirements drastically (it remains O(n))

Comment: @MBo I never said it would require more than O(n) extraa space. Theoretically you can save O(n) space vs your solution by ignoring lower or upper bound *and* recomputing for each query. The space saving measure you implemented applies to both solutions so space vs time still holds. I get a feeling like you think I'm criticizing what you wrote, I am just pointing out the tradeoff.

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar I missed last zero in the description of `(10000, 1000, 0.2)` range start value. Example added. Note that value 15000 refers to the second range from 10000 to 50000